# I am having problems debugging the VBA code below to generate geometric brownian motion simulation of stock price

Tags: excel, vba

I have tried so many times to debug the code below, but still return #VALUE! and I have no idea why. I intend to generate simulations of geometric brownian motion simulation based on a set of epsilon given.

```
Function GBM_sim(S0 As Double, mu As Double, sigma As Double, TTM As Double, d_t As Double, Epsilons As Range) As Variant
    Dim noSteps As Integer
    Dim noPaths As Integer
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim mu_j As Double
    Dim sigma_j As Double
    Dim Width As Integer
    Dim Stocks_t() As Double
    
    noSteps = Round(TTM / d_t)
    noPaths = Epsilons.Columns.Count
    Width = Epsilons.Rows.Count
    ReDim Stocks_t(1 To noSteps, 1 To noPaths)
    For j = 1 To noPaths
        mu_j = mu.Cells(1, j)
        sigma_j = sigma.Cells(1, j)
        For i = 1 To noSteps
            Stocks_t(i) = Stocks_t(i - 1) * Exp((mu_j - (sigma_j ^ 2) / 2) * d_t) + sigma_j * (d_t ^ 0.5) * Epsilons.Cells(i, j)
        Next i
    Next j
    GBM_sim = Stocks_t()

End Function
```

Thanks a lot for the help everyone. I have uploaded sample data for your reference.
[These are my input, S0, mu and sigma](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mh8H6.png)

TTM is 2/12 and d_t is 1/365.

my epsilon is an array as follow.
[The epsilon that I am using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYyo9.png)

This is what happened when I tried to call the function.
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVrSd.png)

Comment: Both parameters `mu` and `sigma` are double, you can't use `mu.Cells()` and `sigma.Cells()`. Please show your formula in OP. Maybe both parameters should be defined as `Range` ( It's just my guess ).

Comment: Also, you have defined `ReDim Stocks_t(1 To noSteps, 1 To noPaths)` and later, in the inner loop, you use `... Stocks_t(i - 1)...`: there is no `Stocks_t(0)`. You aren't using the first argument (`S0`) anywhere.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment, I have amend it to the following but it still does not work.

Comment: Where is your revised code?

Comment: I just edited the question, please have a look

Comment: For your information, my input S0, mu, sigma are both row vector and epsilon is a matrix.

Comment: Have you fixed the last point on @VBasic2008's comment?

Comment: `ReDim S0(1 To noSteps, 1 To noPaths)` S0 is an argument(Range object), why you redim is as an array? `noPath` is not defined and assigned any value. If `Dim mu_j As Range`, then `mu_j = mu.Cells(1, j)` doesn't work.

Comment: Call your function from a Sub, and not from the worksheet - that way you can see exactly where the error is and fix it.

Comment: `option explicit` would help.

Comment: Do you have any test data that you can share?

Comment: @taller hey wondering how can I adjust my code from there? both my S0, mu and sigma are row vectors actually.

Comment: are you now calling from a sub? And have you applied option explicit?

Comment: I have applied option explicit and updated my code. Would u please have a look?

Comment: You're still using `Redim` on a range, that's used on arrays, not on ranges. If you want a range as an array, use `Dim arrMu: arrMu = mu.Value`. Note: if you Redim an array, all the values are erased, unless you use `Redim Preserve` but you can only adjust the second dimension (columns in the array). Also, Option Explicit is added at the very top of a code's page (above your Function in this case)

Comment: Install the free and fantastic Rubberduck addin for VBA.  The code nspections will help you understand which lines of code are incorrect.  You need to ensure that your code compiles (In the IDE use Debug.Compile).

Comment: Hi all, I have added sample data that I am using. Wondering if you can have a look again. grateful for that!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what your *geometric brownian motion simulation* is supposed to look like, you didn't really give any testing data or expected results but in the comments people mentioned using a sub to see what was going wrong, so I did:

```
Function GBM_sim_OLD(S0 As Range, mu As Range, sigma As Range, TTM As Double, d_t As Double, Epsilons As Range) As Variant
    Dim noSteps As Integer, noPaths As Integer
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, Width
    Dim mu_j As Double, sigma_j As Double
    Dim Stocks_t() As Double
    
    noSteps = Round(TTM / d_t)
    noPaths = Epsilons.Columns.Count
    Width = Epsilons.Rows.Count
    ReDim Stocks_t(1 To noSteps, 1 To noPaths)
    For j = 1 To noPaths
        mu_j = mu.Cells(1, j)
        sigma_j = sigma.Cells(1, j)
        For i = 1 To noSteps
            If i > 1 Then
                Stocks_t(i, j) = Stocks_t(i - 1, j) * Exp((mu_j - (sigma_j ^ 2) / 2) * d_t) + sigma_j * (d_t ^ 0.5) * Epsilons.Cells(i, j)
            End If
        Next i
    Next j
    GBM_sim_OLD = Stocks_t()

End Function

Sub test()
    Dim arr
    arr = GBM_sim_OLD(Range("A1:J1"), Range("A2:J2"), Range("A3:J3"), Range("K3").Value, Range("L3").Value, Range("A1:J3"))
    Range("A5").Resize(UBound(arr, 1), UBound(arr, 2)).Value = arr
End Sub
```

You were changing things without knowing what exactly, i.e. Redim'ing your range or setting the doubles to range for (nearly) everything. I started off from the first code you gave because of this so it's mostly the same to what you found(?).
In the Sub I use an array so I could resize the range to what it needed to be with the UBounds.
In the function there was `ReDim Stocks_t(1 To noSteps, 1 To noPaths)` but then there was only one dimension spoken of later so I adjusted `Stocks_t(i) = Stocks_t(i - 1)` to `Stocks_t(i, j) = Stocks_t(i - 1, j)` (was mentioned in the comments) but also had to add the `If i > 1 Then` clause because of that "i-1" logic.
As for what the logic is actually supposed to be for i = 1, I'm not quite sure.

This is the result from both the sub and then later as a formula:
[image]

Hope that makes it a bit more clear what (not) to do.

**EDIT:**
This is the result I get with your actual data, "Blad2" is sheet2 where your epsilons are on.

[image]

Formula used:

> =GBM_sim_OLD(A1:P1;A2:P2;A3:P3;A5;A6;Blad2!A2:P43)

Comment: Hey! thanks so much for your help. But I am still struggling to get the outcome. I have uploaded a sample data. Would you please have a look at it? Thanks so much!

Comment: You haven't clarified what the logic around the i-1 is supposed to be(come). I understand of a logic "looking at the previous row" but what should happen according to the *geometric brownian motion simulation* for the first row?

Comment: I think the loop might need to start from i=2. The i-1 logic is because the simulation is based on black-scholes model. The previous stock price is multiplied by a factor (everything after stocks_t in the formula) to get the next stock stock price.

Comment: Even with the luxury of having image to table converters online (for your epsilons), I still don't know what to expect as a result from the function.

Comment: Hi Notus, thanks for your help a lot! The output of the function is supposed to be an array with same width of the epsilon and length of 42 (same dimension as epsilon).

Comment: I mean, I have that but I don't know if the values are correct.. Ofc, there's that first row that's completely 0 but other than that, it's the correct length/width.

Comment: Hey, I doubt if the first row should be completely 0. Also, I was not able to run the code you provided on my own dataset which I find it weird as well.

Comment: Either you have a logic what needs to happen for i = 1 or you have an empty row, I can't determine that for you but without logic, I can't give it anything either. As for it not working out, I edited my answer with an image of the result using my code and your data (Round(TTM / d_t) is the amount of rows you'll get, not determined by Epsilon's dimension)). Are you sure you're not still using your function (notice I changed the name to GBM_sim_OLD for this purpose)?

Comment: Hey Notus, I am so grateful for your help! But I am still not working and I have added the image of me trying yo call the function. I wonder what is the possible reason for this.

Comment: Apart from the (to me) weird use of AD9# and AD10# (seems to work for you), I don't see anything wrong with your use of the UDF. I've looked for the error together with UDF but can't figure out what's wrong, sorry :/